# fuelSDK replacing "id" with "ObjectID"

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

In Marketing Cloud, I created a data extension with a column "id" that is used as primary key.

When I am querying the the data extension with [fuelSDK Java](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java) the fuelSDk replaces the key "id" sometimes with "ObjectID". This breaks the code, since a null entry is returned where I would expect a result.

Is there a workaround for this? Can replacement of "id" suppressed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is 'NO', there is no workaround.  Long answer is 'YES', you can modify the fuelSDK code to do whatever you want.

The FuelSDK is not being actively maintained - however, since the code is available for import into your project you are able to customize it as needed, including modifying this behavior.

I do not have the code that you will need to change, nor do I think this is the forum for discussion regarding fuelSDK enhancements - but, I think a better solution to your issue would be to change the name of the Data Extension column.